# Regex to extract content from slash to either end of line, slash or query string

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to match the last slash in a path of arbitrary depth to essentially the end of the path. How do I adjust this so example one matches?

```
([^/]+[.html]?)/?\?
```

1. https://www.somedomain/path/some-slug-94690 (no match)
2. https://www.somedomain.com/one/somepath/another-slug?test  (another-slug)
3. https://www.anotherdomain.com/somepath/another-slug/?test (another-slug)
4. https://www.anotherdomain.com/path/another_slug.html?test=true (another-slug)

https://regex101.com/r/bFz9mw/1

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pattern seems to be working:

```
/[^?/]*/?(?=\?|$)
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
/         match a (possibly) final path separator
[^?/]*    match zero or more non / or ? characters
/?        optionally match one more path separator
(?=\?|$)  which is followed by either `?` or the end of the string
```

**Edit:**

If your version of regex does not support lookahead, then use the following similar pattern instead:

```
/[^?/]*/?(?:\?|$)
```

Then, trim off the trailing `?`, should it exist.  On Go, you would use `strings.TrimRight`, with `?` as the character to trim.

Comment: Thanks Tim and for the explanation!

Comment: Thanks for the good question, and I have no idea why you got downvoted (I reversed it, by the way).

Comment: golang doesn't support lookahead.

Comment: I didn't have the language tagged in the initial question, but this still works: https://regex101.com/r/bFz9mw/4/

Comment: @Toto I gave a very similar pattern in case lookarounds are not available.